# How to calculate actual width and height of rotated object in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Am trying to calculate width and height of object i loaded into canvas. When object is not rotated i get correct left right top bottom values, but when i load rotated object in canvas then i not get correct values , so i wonder what will be the logic or math formula to do achieve it.

how am doing.

- initially load image into canvas
- get image data from canvas
- loop through image data to get only colored pixels by using alpha check
- from colored pixel array find min max xy values

  ```
  var temp_ray = [];  // pixel array

      for (var y = 0; y < imgData.height; ++y) {
          for (var x = 0; x < imgData.width; ++x) {
              var index = (y * imgData.width + x) * 4; 
              if(imgData.data[index+3]){  
                  var xc = (index / 4) % imgData.width;   
                  var yc = Math.floor((index / 4) / imgData.width);  
                  temp_ray.push([xc,yc]);     
              }

          }
      }
      if(temp_ray.length > 0){
          var Xind = MaxMin2darray(temp_ray,0);
          var Yind = MaxMin2darray(temp_ray,1);
          var W = parseFloat(Xind['max']) - parseFloat(Xind['min']);
          var H = parseFloat(Yind['max']) - parseFloat(Yind['min']);  
          var center_x = Xind['min'] + (W/2);
          var center_y = Yind['min'] + (H/2);
          // find corners of object

          // find *min x , min y 
          let top_left = temp_ray[Xind['imin']];    // min X priority , min Y   // top left
          // find max x , *min y 
          let top_right = temp_ray[Yind['imin']];    // max X, min Y priority ,   // top right
          // find *max x , min y 
          let bot_right = temp_ray[Xind['imax']];    // max X priority , min Y  // bottom right 
          // find max x , *max y 
          let bot_left = temp_ray[Yind['imax']];    // max X , max Y priority // bottom left  

          var dim = {'W':W,'H':H,'CenterX':center_x,'CenterY':center_y,'top_left':top_left,'top_right':top_right,'bot_right':bot_right,'bot_left':bot_left,'Xend':Xind['max'],'Yend':Yind['max'],'Xstart':Xind['min'],'Ystart':Yind['min'],'Xend':Xind['max'],'Yend':Yind['max']};
          console.log(dim);
      }
  ```

and then using min max xy value find corners of object which works with none rotated objects but not work with rotated/tilted objects.

so any idea how to solve this problem
[image]

- openpnp project is achieving this through opencv, but i think in js we do not have opencv library nor am that pro of java :(.

  https://github.com/openpnp/openpnp/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/openpnp/vision/pipeline/stages/DrawRotatedRects.java

[image]

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/4L13vtaj/

Comment: This question is really broad. what do you define as width an height in your image ? Do your images have a certain shape  (like rectangles)? Or your image could be anything ?
In some simple cases (like rectangles), you could try to rotate the image until you minimize the number of white pixels.

Comment: @Mium i have added image in which i highlighted with and height , no i can have different type of images not only rectangles

Comment: Your example image is not a rectangle. The pins make it a complex shape, and your brain simplified it to a rectangle shape. When you say that you won't have only rectangular shapes, you need to first define how you will simplify these images like your brain did here. Rectangle is easy to program, regular shapes are doable, the more irregular they get, the harder it will be. But you talked only of width and height, only rectangles can be defined by width and height, so what do you want exactly? To draw the border of a simplified version of the shape? Or to get bounding box values?

Comment: @kaiido ya i want To draw the border of a simplified version of the shape , and then want to detect # of corners/spikes in shape like in above image you can see pins if border is drawn on it then i would have about 8 spikes up and 8 down , and other irregular shape like ( https://i.imgur.com/tIGyiOZ.png ) if border is draw i would get about 15 bend points in it.  i will try to draw the border using one method i have in mind. but problem is count and recognizing corners/spikes

Comment: That is still a very broad request... I would start by gathering all the points coordinates (e.g using a [marching-squares algo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares)), and then simplify the produced path with e.g a [Douglas-Peucker Algo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm). Or I would maybe consider checking a library, it seems [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/smoothing-simplifying-flattening/)  has some built-ins that would help in this task.

Comment: @Kaiido ok thanks i will try that , have done borders part but struggling with paper js , is its not returning me plain simplified data(http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/smoothing-simplifying-flattening/)  , paper.js want  to write on canva , i wish i could just get data from it

Answer (score 1):

In some simple cases (like rectangular objects), you could try to rotate the image until you minimize the number of uncolored pixels.

So you start with your image, and for each of the possible 360°, you compute the ratio. This is not perfect, but "doable" simply in pure js.

Here's a pseudoCode that might help you:

```
for degree in [0,365]{
  rotateOriginalImageBy(degree);
  cost[degree] = NemptyPixels/NfilledPixels;
}

predictedDegree = Math.min(cost);
rotateOriginalImageBy(predictedDegree);
compute 2 dimensions;
width = largerDimension;
height = shorterDimension;
```

Begining of an implementation (I edited your jsfiddle):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var rotatioDegree = 45;

var imageObject = new Image();
imageObject.onload = function() {
  var canvasWidth = imageObject.width;
  var canvasHeight = canvasWidth; // not useful since width==height
  document.getElementById('canvas').width = canvasWidth;
  document.getElementById('canvas').height = canvasWidth;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasWidth);
  // Move registration point to the center of the canvas
  ctx.translate(canvasWidth/2, canvasWidth/2)
  ctx.rotate(rotatioDegree*3.1415/180);
  ctx.translate(-canvasWidth/2,-canvasWidth/2)
  ctx.drawImage(imageObject,0,0);
  ctx.translate(canvasWidth/2, canvasWidth/2)
  ctx.rotate(-rotatioDegree*3.1415/180);
  ctx.translate(-canvasWidth/2,-canvasWidth/2)


  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasWidth);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4L13vtaj/17/

If this doesn't work, you could implement some image detection techniques (Mathematical morphology for example). But i think this is outside the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: hmmmm ya that might work in some cases , by guessing rotation , however this will slow the process , also main thing is the finding rotated corners coordinates as from them i will be then able to find angle of tilt too along width and height. so this is the challenging to find the coordinates of  the corners

Comment: I updated the code and inserted a `do a rotation of d degrees`. So you only need to be able to detect filled and empty pixels in order to get the width and height.

Comment: Try the jsfiddle, it is working for 45°. (I didn't iterate over all the degrees, but this what you would get)

Answer (score 1):

If you work with some approximation, you can have something like that; I hope at least it can provide to you some ideas:

```
  // some pixels in this image are not transparent, so we add a tollerance
  // you can try to remove the second condition.
  const isNotEmpty = (color) => color && color < 0xffaaaaaa;

  function getTop(buff, w, h) {
    for (let y = 0; y < h; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        let i = y * w + x;
        if (isNotEmpty(buff[i])) {
          return {x, y}
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function getRight(buff, w, h) {
      for (let x = w; x >=0; x--) {
        for (let y = 0; y < h; y++) {
          let i = y * w + x;
          if (isNotEmpty(buff[i])) {
            return {x, y}
          }
      }
    }
  }

  function getBottom(buff, w, h) {
    for (let y = h; y >= 0; y--) {
      for (let x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        let i = y * w + x;
        if (isNotEmpty(buff[i])) {
          return {x, y}
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function getLeft(buff, w, h) {
      for (let x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < h; y++) {
          let i = y * w + x;
          if (isNotEmpty(buff[i])) {
            return {x, y}
          }
      }
    }
  }

  async function main(imageSource) {
    const  canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const imageObject = new Image();
    imageObject.src = imageSource;
    await new Promise(r => imageObject.onload = r);

    const w = canvas.width = imageObject.width;
    const h = canvas.height = imageObject.height;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.drawImage(imageObject, 0, 0);

    const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
    const buff = new Uint32Array(imgData.data.buffer);

    const points = [
      getTop(buff, w, h),
      getRight(buff, w, h),
      getBottom(buff, w, h),
      getLeft(buff, w, h)
    ];

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000ff"
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    ctx.lineTo(points[1].x, points[1].y);
    ctx.lineTo(points[2].x, points[2].y);
    ctx.lineTo(points[3].x, points[3].y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  main(/* image's url*/);
```

Here the link for testing: https://codepen.io/zer0/pen/zLxyQV

There are several problem with this approach: as said, with irregular images, it's not precise, in fact you will see the pin are making the image's bounding box a little bit smaller.
But the thing can be worse: try in the link above to use the 2nd image, that is quite irregular, and you will see.

Of course we can compensate, using also a bit more complex algorithm instead this simple one, but the question is: what the expected result for something like the 2nd image? Depends by that you can decide how to proceed.

Comment: ya you right the pins make it complex , but i wonder how the openpnp project is doing it , as you can see the 2nd image i attached is from openpnp ( https://github.com/openpnp/ ) vision section

Comment: As said, you can do it – you just use a bit more complex algorithm – the problem is: how you – or openpnp – would expect to "boxing" irregular shapes like the 2nd I added in my example on codepen? Depends by that, you can use the right approach.